# Structural tuple-like / Wrapping a variadic set of template parameters values in a struct

Tags: c++, tuples, c++20, constexpr

I find myself wanting/needing to use a variadic composite type as a template parameter. Unfortunately, `std::tuple<>` is not a [structural type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#:%7E:text=structural), which makes the obvious approach a no-go:

```cpp
#include <tuple>

template<typename... Ts>
struct composite {
  std::tuple<Ts...> operands;
};

template<auto v>
void foo() {}

int main() {
  constexpr composite tmp{std::make_tuple(1,2,3)};
  foo<tmp>();  // <----- Nope!
}
```

Is there a reasonable way to build such a composite in a manner that works as a structural type?

Since the MCVE in isolation is trivially solvable as "just make `foo()` a variadic template", here's a more representative example:

[On godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GsWzGMGMa)

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T, template <typename...> typename U>
concept TemplatedConfig = requires(T x) {
  { U(x) } -> std::same_as<T>;
  // A few more things identifying T as a valid config
};

template<auto Config>
struct proc;

// Basic
struct Basic {};

template<Basic v>
struct proc<v> {
    constexpr int foo() { return 0; }
};

// Annotated
template<typename T>
struct Annotated {
    T v;
    int annotation;
};

template<TemplatedConfig<Annotated> auto v>
struct proc<v> {
    constexpr int foo() { return 1; }
};

// ... more config / specialization pairs ...

// Composite
template<typename... Parts>
struct Composite {
    std::tuple<Parts...> parts;
};

template<TemplatedConfig<Composite> auto v>
struct proc<v> {
    constexpr int foo() { return 2; }
};


int main() {
    constexpr Basic a = Basic{};
    constexpr Annotated b{a, 12};
    constexpr Composite c{std::make_tuple(a, b)};

    static_assert(proc<a>{}.foo() == 0);
    static_assert(proc<b>{}.foo() == 1);
    static_assert(proc<c>{}.foo() == 2);   <----- :(
}
```

**Edit:** If anyone is curious what a (almost) fully-realized tuple class based on the accepted answer looks like: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ThaGjbo67

Comment: I know this me-too-great-question comment will be deleted soon, but hey, great question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own structural tuple-like class?
Something like:

```
template <std::size_t I, typename T>
struct tuple_leaf
{
    T data;    
};

template <typename T> struct tag{ using type = T; };

template <typename Seq, typename...>
struct tuple_impl;

template <std::size_t... Is, typename... Ts>
struct tuple_impl<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...> : tuple_leaf<Is, Ts>...
{
    constexpr tuple_impl(Ts... args) : tuple_leaf<Is, Ts>{args}... {}
};

template <typename T, std::size_t I> constexpr const T& get(const tuple_leaf<I, T>& t) { return t.data; }
template <typename T, std::size_t I> constexpr T& get(tuple_leaf<I, T>& t) { return t.data; }
template <std::size_t I, typename T> constexpr const T& get(const tuple_leaf<I, T>& t) { return t.data; }
template <std::size_t I, typename T> constexpr T& get(tuple_leaf<I, T>& t) { return t.data; }


template <std::size_t I, typename T>
tag<T> tuple_element_tag(const tuple_leaf<I, T>&);

template <std::size_t I, typename Tuple>
using tuple_element = decltype(tuple_element_tag<I>(std::declval<Tuple>()));

template <std::size_t I, typename Tuple>
using tuple_element_t = typename tuple_element<I, Tuple>::type;

template <typename ... Ts>
using tuple = tuple_impl<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>, Ts...>;
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5GTPe7788)

Comment: Huh, for some reason I was expecting that approach to be a lot more daunting. This sort of brings the question: What is preventing `std::tuple` from being a structural type then? Something to do with public undocumented members not being allowed in the standard library? I don't think empty-base-optimization would be interfering, but maybe I've got that wrong?

Comment: @Frank. The `private` members of tuple make it not a structural type.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Let me rephrase the question: "If making the members of `std::tuple<>` public with reserved identifiers is all that's preventing `std::tuple` from being structural, then why was it not done?"

Comment: @Frank. Because you can't simply use`std::tuple<Types...>{}.data` to get the members you want since it itself contains `sizeof...(Types)` member variables of different types called `data`.

Comment: @Frank: The structural types rules were written only at the very last moment for C++20 to fix serious issues with the previous class-type NTTP rules that were properly understood only late in the process.  `std::tuple` may very well be made structural in the future, although not for C++23 (which has suffered predictably from the pandemic).